# Django: Display thumbnails in ListView from Queryset

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-views, django-queryset

UPDATE: here is my progress in the last week, view.py:

```
class PersoListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'sconsult/search.html'
    context_object_name = 'search_list'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        get_image = self.request.GET.get('q')
        context = super(PersoListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        perkz = File.objects.select_related().filter(
        citid__persoid=get_image, filedoc__page='1', filedoc__docid='2').values(
        'filedoc__docimage', 'filedoc__docid', 'filedesc')

        for perko in perkz:
            porkz = perko['filedoc__docimage']
            tmp = 'sconsult/static/sconsult/media/images/' + perko['filedesc'] + '.jpg'
            img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(porkz))
            img.save(tmp, 'JPEG')
            img64 = base64.b64encode(open(tmp, 'rb').read()).decode('utf-8').replace('\n', '')
            img_tag = '{0}'.format(img64)
            print(img_tag)
        context['img_list'] = img_tag

        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        get_search = self.request.GET.get('q')

        if get_search is not None:
            perso = File.objects.select_related().filter(
            citid__persoid=get_search,filedoc__page='1',filedoc__docid='1').values(
            'citid__name', 'citid__lastname', 'fileid', 
            'officeid__officedesc', 'citizenid')
        return perso
```

and this is my relevant search.html template:

```
           {% for person in search_list %}
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="{%  url 'sconsult:detail' person.fileid %}">
                        <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{ img_list }}" alt="Imagen" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 175px; height: 200px;"/></a>
                            <div class="col-sm-14">
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h2><p style="font-size:20px">{{ person.citid__name }} {{ person.citid__lastname }}</p></h2>

                                    <a href="{%  url 'sconsult:detail' person.fileid %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                                       role="button">View Details</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        {% endfor %}
```

{{ img_list }}

I am fairly new to django and excuse my idents as they don't show up like this in the files. This field 'filedoc__docimage' is in bytearray inside the database: I know it's not the best idea, but that's what found. With this setup, I can retrieve the image as base64enconded and pass it to the template, the problem is that if I use a for loop for the 2 ListView Records, the print() gives me a vertical list of every character:

```
    img_tag = '{0}'.format(img64)
    for kaku in img_tag:
        print(kaku)
context['img_list'] = img_tag
```

If I don't do a for loop and `print(img_tag)` the listview displays the first image to the 2 records. What can I do? to fix this?

Comment: Nobody? really? so sad.

Comment: This is late but your question is not clear. It is difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve, so, providing direction, suggestion or answers is near impossible. Please edit your question so it can help future users.